# A good file path builder library for C#?

Tags: c#, .net, path

`System.IO.Path` in .NET is notoriously clumsy to work with. In my various projects I keep encountering the same usage scenarios which require repetitive, verbose and thus error-prone code snippets that use `Path.Combine`, `Path.GetFileName`, `Path.GetDirectoryName`, `String.Format`, etc. Scenarios like:

- changing the extension for a given file name
- changing the directory path for a given file name
- building a file path using string formatting (like "`Package{0}.zip`")
- building a path without resorting to using hard-coded directory delimiters like `\` (since they don't work on Linux on Mono)
- etc etc

Before starting to write my own `PathBuilder` class or something similar: is there a good (and proven) open-source implementation of such a thing in C#?

UPDATE: OK, just an illustration of what I mean:

```
        string zipFileName = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(directoryName) + ".zip";
        zipFileName = Path.Combine(
            Path.GetDirectoryName(directoryName), 
            zipFileName);
```

A nicer fluent API could look like this:

```
Path2 directoryName = "something";
Path2 zipFileName = directoryName.Extension("zip");
```

Or when building a path:

```
Path2 directoryName = "something";
Path2 directory2 = directoryName.Add("subdirectory")
    .Add("Temp").Add("myzip.zip");
```

instead of

```
string directory2 = Path.Combine(Path.Combine(Path.Combine(
     directoryName, "subdirectory"), "Temp"), "myzip.zip");
```

I actually did implement something like this in the past, but in a separate project. I've decided now to reuse it as a standalone C# class added "as link" in VisualStudio in my other projects. It's not a cleanest solution, but I guess it will do. If you're interested, [you can see the code here](http://mywiki.igorbrejc.net/index.php?title=Code_Snippets#PathBuilder).

Comment: I'm curious as to why you think these may be error-prone?

Comment: Because you need to rewrite the same or similar code in a lot of places, each time reinventing the wheel. Sooner or later you'll end up with a bug (wrong method called etc).

Comment: I take it you are aware of `FileInfo` and `DirectoryInfo` already?

Comment: What do FileInfo and DirectoryInfo have to do with path building? I'm not talking about creating files/directories, just working with paths as strings. Take a look at the code link at the bottom of my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might also want to checkout the "[NDepend.Helpers.FileDirectoryPath](http://www.codeplex.com/FileDirectoryPath)" library.

Answer (score 8):

You should take a look at the enhancements to `Path` in v4 of the framework first.

For example, [`Path.Combine`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd991142%28VS.100%29.aspx) will now accept multiple path fragments, rather than having to nest them.

Comment: Nice, but I'm looking for something that will work for the existing code base (at least 3.5).

Answer (score 3):

System.IO.Path already covers the following from your list:

- changing the extension for a given file name
- changing the directory path for a given file name
- building a path without resorting to using hard-coded directory delimiters like \ (since they don't work on Linux on Mono)

And you can easily create a class or some extensions methods to do the remaining, based on the `Path` class.

Comment: I didn't say it wasn't possible. I'm just saying that the API could be much better.

Comment: I'm with Henk here. The existing API is pretty good. Reshape it with extension methods if you want it to look different, but e.g. your example above doesn't use the already present Path.ChangeExtension method. I'd have a look for better ways to do what you're trying to do with the API you have before looking at changing API.

Comment: Iain, it's not as if I haven't used it for some 5-6 years now :). So I guess after such a long time I can have an opinion that it's _not_ pretty good. But I guess that's a matter of taste.But i recommend taking a look at APIs for things like Windsor Castle, FluentNHibernate, AutoMapper and similar.

Comment: Another example of why I think it's not a good API. Let's say you have a path to a directory. How do you get the parent path? You call GetDirectoryName(). Bad naming, in my opinion. First of all, I already _have_ a directory, so what does this method give me (if I'm a newbie and I don't know). Second, you get the _whole_ path, not just the name of the directory. It's such little things that make an API good or bad. The guys who did System.IO.Path should have taken a look at Microsoft's own design guidelines: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229042.aspx

Answer (score 3):

[FluentPath](http://weblogs.asp.net/bleroy/archive/2010/03/10/fluentpath-a-fluent-wrapper-around-system-io.aspx) looks nice and neat.

Comment: Yes, something in this direction, although FluentPath is more ambitious, it wraps IO file system operations too.